# Sending a JSON string from Javascript to Python server (Socket)

Tags: javascript, python, json, sockets

I have a basic HTML form. The input from the form is collected and stored as a JSON object, in a Javascript file.

I know that you can send JSON to the python server, and have successfully done so with hard-coding it into a python client.

However, I don't know how to set up a socket in the Javascript file, and thus send the JSON to the server (the python socket).

I have a python server, currently connected to a python client to send basic messages between them and to test sending and parsing JSON. I have very little knowledge of the client-server world, so any help would be hugely appreciated!

Comment: As per your problem you can try sending HTTP post requests from javascript to the python server to a certain endpoint where you can receive and format the JSON.

Comment: why do you want to use socket for this ? It may need extra code to make it useful - so you will have to create something similar to HTTP.

Comment: if you use popular `XMLHttpRequest` or modern `fetch` then it will also use `socket` but it will send data using `HTTP` protocol - it means first it sends headers, next it sends empty line (`"\n\n"`) and finally it sends your data. As I know web browser reads headers from sockets using `read(1)` until it gets `"\n\n"` which means end of headers. And one of the heades `Content-Length` should have information about size of data which browser uses to read data - `read(content_length)`. So you can do the same in your socket.